# Redis Cluster K8s - replication password

Tags: kubernetes, redis

I'm trying to get my redis cluster up and running but I'm unable to properly setup a password authentication for my clients. As soon as I set a password using `--requirepass` the replication is not working anymore. So I googled on I found out that redis uses a separate password for replication. This can be set using `masterauth`, please also see: https://redis.io/topics/replication.
So I also tried to start with `--masterauth` but with no success. Has somebody any idea if `--masterauth` can be used as a parameter I can pass to the `redis-server` command at start-up as the docs don't refer to this directly. And before referring to helm, please be aware that my whole deployment is setup using `kustomize.io` and `helm` is not my preferred way to go for the moment.

I also tried something [like this](https://github.com/AliyunContainerService/redis-cluster/issues/4) with no success.

This is what my redis-cluster.yaml looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 6379
    targetPort: 6379
    name: redis
  selector:
    name: redis
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-slave
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 6379
    targetPort: 6379
    name: redis
  selector:
    name: redis-slave
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis
  labels:
    name: redis
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: redis
    spec:
      subdomain:
      containers:
      - name: redis
        image: redis:6.0.9-alpine
        command:
          - redis-server
        args:
          - "--protected-mode"
          - "no"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis-slave
  labels:
    name: redis-slave
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: redis-slave
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: redis-slave
    spec:
      subdomain: redis-slave
      containers:
      - name: redis
        image: redis:6.0.9-alpine
        command:
          - "redis-server"
        args:
          - "--slaveof"
          - "redis.default.svc.cluster.local"
          - "6379"
          - "--protected-mode"
          - "no"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to configure a password on redis container:

1. Fast implementation:

```
      containers:
      - args:
        - -c
        - |-
          echo -e 'maxmemory 183500800
          maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru
          stop-writes-on-bgsave-error no
          slaveof redis-master.default.svc.cluster.local
          requirepass YOUR_PASSWORD
          masterauth MASTER_PASSWORD' | docker-entrypoint.sh -
        command:
        - /bin/sh
        image: redis:6.0.9-alpine
        name: redis-slave
```

2. Better practice:

- Use a ConfigMap for each Deployment, mounted on `/etc/redis/redis.conf`, having the specific configuration and run the container without `args` or `command`.

More Redis 6.0 config parameters and documentation can be found here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/redis/redis/6.0/redis.conf

Comment: Will check on this by tomorrow, thanks in advance :D

Comment: but where does masterauth gets handled?

Comment: You can use `masterauth` as I later edited in my Answer. https://redis.io/topics/replication#setting-a-replica-to-authenticate-to-a-master